# How to generate XPath of a specific Identifer in an attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the ff. XML format given to us by a backend server.

```
<App name="Stackoverflow">  
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute>
            <Name>DisplayName</Name>
            <Value>Sample_Name</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <Name>Notes</Name>
            <Value>Sample_note</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <Name>id</Name>
            <Value>stackoverflow.com</Value>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</App>
```

How do I get the value of the Attribute Name id which is stackoverflow.com without specifying the index to which the attribute is located?. I could already get the value of the Attribute Name id by specifying an index like the one below,

```
/App[@name="Stackoverflow"]/Attributes/Attribute[3]/Value/text()
```

but how do I make it dynamic and search through all attributes if ever the output of the server with the Attribute Name id changes, i.e if its index moved to index 2, 4 etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify the `Name()/text()` instead of index.

```
//App[@name="Stackoverflow"]/Attributes/Attribute[Name/text()="id"]/Value/text()
```